# Help identifying utensil looking round support piece with 2 bars

Tags: part-identification

Here is a picture of the piece (red brick below it is just for showing the size).

It has "© LEGO" and "8-01" written on it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This piece is called [Space binoculars or electrobinoculars](https://rebrickable.com/parts/30304/equipment-space-binoculars-aka-electrobinoculars/) and has part number 30304.